# How to convert String to Graphic datatype in JPQL

Tags: java, jpa, db2, jpql, openjpa

I have the department_name field with Graphic datatype in DB2 table
In JPQL I tried to use 'G' type cast to convert string to Graphic datatype.

```
WHERE m.departmentName <> G'あり'
```

But the JPQL doesn't understand G and throw an exception.

Kindly help me.

Comment: What `exception`? What is the error? What is the DB2 version and platform?

Answer (score 0):

I used deferPrepares to false as the following and the problem goes away. Now it can compare with String and Graphics data type.

```
db2://host:portNumber/DBname:deferPrepares=false;
```

> The deferred prepare means that the driver works without the benefit of described parameters or result set metadata until  execution time: undescribed input data is sent as is to the  server, without any data type cross-conversion of the input data.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_8.2.0/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/ad/c0010273.htm